# Solving the recurrence $3T(\frac{n}{4}) + n \cdot \log n$ by the Recurrence Tree method

Tags: algorithms, recurrence-relations

I am trying to solve the recurrence $3T\left(\frac{n}{4}\right) + n \cdot \log n$ by using the Recurrence Tree method. I've solved it until here:

$= 3 \cdot \frac{n}{4} \log \frac{n}{4}$

$= 3 \cdot 3 \cdot \frac{n}{16} \log \frac{n}{16}$

$= \sum_{i=0}^{log_4(n) + 1} \frac{3^i}{4^i} \cdot n \log(\frac{n}{4^i})$

$= n \sum_{i=0}^{log_4(n) + 1} \frac{3^i}{4^i} \left[\log(n) - log_4(4^i)\right]$

$= n\log{n} \sum_{i=0}^{\log_4(n) + 1} \frac{3^i}{4^i} - n \sum_{i=0}^{\log_4(n)} \frac{3^i}{4^i} i$

But after this I do not know how to handle the second part of the equation after subtraction. In particular, if I take the sum until infinity of the above expression, then the sum of the $i$ term in the above part would sum to infinity.

Could anyone please help me regarding this? Am I making some kind of a mistake? The final recurrence should solve to $n \log n$ (as verified by the Master's Thereom method)

Comment: It seems your misconception is to believe that the series $$\sum \frac{3^i}{4^i}i$$ diverges. Actually it converges hence the last RHS in your post is indeed $\Theta(n\log n)$. (As an aside, note that the formulation of your question is one of the worst I have seen recently on this site.)

Comment: @Did Wrongly formulated in what particular way?

Comment: Tons of ways. The first one: there is no recurrence in your title. Second one: the title confuses $n$ and $N$. Third one: the body repeats the faults of the title then turns to an "equation" with no LHS. And so on.

Comment: @QPTR I think you can solve it using the [Akra-Bazzi theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akra%E2%80%93Bazzi_method).

Comment: @Did My bad, partially corrected it. I am not sure how best to represent the treeness of the recurrence tree while solving it, so yeah, thats a bit wrong technically. Would you explain the convergence part a bit more?

Comment: "My bad" Obviously. "partially corrected it" Why only partially? "Would you explain the convergence part a bit more?" What is this newspeak for? You mean you are not aware of the convergence/divergence of the series $$\sum_n nr^n\ ?$$

Comment: @AlexVong Over here the subproblems are of the same size so it seems like `Akra-Bazzi` theorem may not apply

Comment: @Did I am not sure how best to show the summing up of the levels in the tree.

Comment: @Did Well I am in the sense that I could solve$ \sum nr^n$ by converting it to $ r \sum nr^{n-1}$ , but it doesn't look like its going to give a $\log$ n answer.

Comment: @QPTR Firstly, Akra-Bazzi theorem is a generalization of Master theorem (it is more powerful), so it works for subproblems of the same size as well. Secondly, it is usually difficult/painful to find explicit formula for recurrence relation. It is usually good enough (at least when I studied in computer science) to bound the sum above and below by integrals and conclude $T \in \Theta(n \log(n))$

Comment: @Did Oh, it does give a $\log n $ answer. Something like $ \frac{(- nr^{n-1} (1 - r) + (1 - r^n))}{(1 - r^2)}$ Is that correct?

Comment: Correct or not it is irrelevant. As explained in my first comment, all that matters is that the series $\sum (3/4)^i$ and $\sum i(3/4)^i$ both converge hence your last RHS is $n\log n\Theta(1)-n\Theta(1)=\Theta(n\log n)$.

Comment: @QPTR Please accept the answer if you find it useful. Feel free to ask if you don't understand my answer.

Comment: Why are we taking infinite sum in these types of problems when we know there are going to be finite terms (some log n) till the problem size becomes 1?

Answer (score 1):

There are at least two methods to solve this problem.

We first present the [**Akra-Bazzi theorem**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akra%E2%80%93Bazzi_method):

If the recurrence is of the form
$$T(x) = g(x) + \sum_{i = 1}^{k} a_i T(b_i x + h_i(x))$$
for all $x > x_0$ with the following conditions

1. sufficient base cases
2. $a_i > 0$ and $0 < b_i < 1$
3. $|g(x)| \in O(x^c)$
4. $|h_i(x)| \in O\left(\frac{x}{(\log x)^2}\right)$

Then
$$T \in \Theta\left(x^p \left(1 + \int_{1}^{x} \frac{g(u)}{u^{p + 1}}\right)\right)$$
where $p$ is the solution to the equation $$\sum_{i = 1}^{k} a_i b_i^p = 1$$.

**Solution 0**:

We simply apply the theorem.

Note $k = 1$, $g(x) = x \log x$, $a_1 = 1$, $b_1 = \frac{1}{4}$ and $h_1(x) = 0$.

Clearly they satisfy the assumptions, so we now solve the equation
$$\sum_{i = 1}^{1} a_i b_i^p = 1$$
$$\iff a_1 b_1^p = 1$$
$$\iff \left(\frac{1}{4}\right)^p = 1$$
$$\iff p = 0$$
Now proceed to solve the integral 
$$\int_{1}^{x} \frac{u \log u}{u^{0 + 1}} = \int_{1}^{x} \log u = [u \log u - u]_1^x = x \log x - x + 1$$
So we have
$$T \in \Theta(x^0 (1 + x \log x - x + 1)) = \Theta(x \log x)$$

**Solution 1**:

Our plan is to express the recurrence in the form of sum, bound it by integrals and hope that the lower bound is $\Theta(n \log n)$ while the upper bound is $O(n \log n)$.

First, we put $n = 4^k$ and obtain
$$T(4^k) = 3^1 T(4^{k - 1}) + 3^0 4^k \log 4^k$$
$$= 3^2 T(4^{k - 2}) + 3^1 4^{k - 1} \log 4^{k - 1} + 3^0 4^k \log 4^k$$
$$= 3^3 T(4^{k - 3}) + 3^2 4^{k - 2} \log 4^{k - 2} + 3^1 4^{k - 1} \log 4^{k - 1} + 3^0 4^k \log 4^k$$
$$\vdots$$
$$= 3^k 4^0 T(1) + 3^{k - 1} 4^1 \log 4^1 + 3^{k - 2} 4^2 \log 4^2 + \dots + 3^1 4^{k - 1} \log 4^{k - 1} + 3^0 4^k \log 4^k$$
$$= 3^k \left(T(1) + \sum_{j = 1}^{k} \left(\frac{4}{3}\right)^j \log 4^j \right)$$
$$= 3^k \left(T(1) + \log 4 \sum_{j = 1}^{k} j \left(\frac{4}{3}\right)^j\right)$$
Now we can bound the sum by integrals since the function is monotone increasing
$$\int_{0}^{k} x \left(\frac{4}{3}\right)^x \le \sum_{j = 1}^{k} j \left(\frac{4}{3}\right)^j \le \int_{1}^{k + 1} x \left(\frac{4}{3}\right)^x$$
Put $a = \frac{4}{3}$

Note $$x a^x = x e^{x \log a}$$
Next we evaluate the integral using integration by parts
$$\int x a^x = \int x e^{x \log a} = \frac{1}{\log a} \left(x e^{x \log a} - \int e^{x \log a}\right)$$
$$= \frac{1}{\log a} \left(x e^{x \log a} - \frac{1}{\log a} e^{x \log a}\right) + C = \frac{a^x}{\log a} \left(x - \frac{1}{\log a} \right) + C$$
So
$$\int_{0}^{k} x \left(\frac{4}{3}\right)^x = \left[\frac{a^x}{\log a} \left(x - \frac{1}{\log a} \right) \right]_{0}^{k} = \frac{a^k}{\log a} \left(k - \frac{1}{\log a} \right) + \frac{1}{(\log a)^2} \in \Omega(k a^k)$$
and
$$\int_{1}^{k + 1} x \left(\frac{4}{3}\right)^x = \left[\frac{a^x}{\log a} \left(x - \frac{1}{\log a} \right) \right]_{1}^{k + 1} = \frac{a^{k + 1}}{\log a} \left(k + 1 - \frac{1}{\log a} \right) - \frac{a}{\log a} \left(1 - \frac{1}{\log a} \right) \in O(k a^k)$$
So one concludes
$$\sum_{j = 1}^{k} j \left(\frac{4}{3}\right)^j \in \Theta(k a^k)$$
Finally, assuming $T(1) \in \Theta(1)$, one has
$$T(n) = 3^k \left(T(1) + \log 4 \sum_{j = 1}^{k} j \left(\frac{4}{3}\right)^j\right)$$
$$\in \Theta(3^k) \Theta(k a^k) = \Theta \left(3^k k \left(\frac{4}{3}\right)^k\right) = \Theta(k 4^k) = \Theta(n \log_4 n) = \Theta(n \log n)$$

Comment: Thanks so much for the answer, I apologize for the delay, I'll definitely accept your answer, just need to understand the Akra-Bazzi theorem a bit better.